# Neovim open file with search pattern not escaped?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, nvim

I'm trying to run the command:

```
nvim "./some-file" '+/Text (with/slash)'
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing command line:
E486: Pattern not found: Text (with
```

And the command line arguments after running `:exe '!tr "\0" " " </proc/' . getpid() . '/cmdline'` gives me:

```
nvim /tmp/.tmpxn2hIQ +/GitHub (bookit/issues)
```

But I don't really know how it's processing it.
Am I missing something about shell expansion?

I can run with the expected result of `'+/Text (with/slash)'`.

```
echo '+/Text (with/slash)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a shell issue. It is `nvim` doesn't understand this pattern as a valid search pattern. I'm afraid the only solution would be to use backslash:

```
nvim "./some-file" '+/Text (with\/slash)'
```

By the way my nvim gives me the different error:

```
$ cat afile
a
Text (with/slash)
c

$ nvim -u NONE afile '+/Text (with/slash)'
```

```
Error detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: /Text (with/slash)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: thank you! It was indeed what was going on was that nvim was interpreting the slash as something else (not sure what?) but it is working now when the slash is escaped. It didn't help that I was also trying to run this through a few program formats as well so it was hard to come up with a small example. Thanks again!